# Solution of Poisson equation in the limit of vanishing source

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, poissons-equation

Given the Poisson equation
$$\vec{\nabla} ^2 u(\vec{r}) = f(\vec{r})$$ 
and its solution as a convolution with the appropriate Green's function
$$u(\vec{r}) = \int G(\vec{r},\vec{r}^\prime) f(\vec{r}^\prime)\, \mathrm{d}\vec{r}^\prime, $$
over an appropriate domain, my question is what happens when we take $f \to 0$?

We then obtain Laplace's equation $\vec{\nabla} ^2 u_0(\vec{r}) = 0$, which can be solved by several methods depending on the context.

In particular, I am confused by the following: what is the full solution to the Poisson equation? Is it

1. $u = u_0 + \int G(\vec{r},\vec{r}^\prime) f(\vec{r}^\prime)\, \mathrm{d}\vec{r}^\prime$, where $u_0$ is harmonic, in which case 
   $$\lim_{f \to 0} \int G(\vec{r},\vec{r}^\prime) f(\vec{r}^\prime)\, \mathrm{d}\vec{r}^\prime \stackrel{?}{=} 0 $$
   making some kind of intuitive sense?
2. Or, is the harmonic part $u_0$ somehow already contained in the convolution integral? If so, how does 
   $$\lim_{f \to 0} \int G(\vec{r},\vec{r}^\prime) f(\vec{r}^\prime)\, \mathrm{d}\vec{r}^\prime \stackrel{?}{=} u_0(\vec{r}) $$
   work?

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't said what the domain/boundary conditions are. If it's on the full space then sending $f \to 0$ sends $u \to 0$. If it's not then it's not so clear why you have a convolution solution at all. At any rate, if $f \to 0$ in an appropriate sense (say in $L^2$) then its convolution with a "reasonable" kernel should also go to zero. This is a bit tricky because the Green's function is not the nicest kernel in the world, but that's the intuition at least.

Comment: I am interested in the case where $u_0(\vec{r}) = \theta$, where $\theta \in (0,2\pi[$ is given by $\arctan2(y,x)$ where $\vec{r} = (x,y)$. The domain is the full space $\Omega = \field{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$, but where we exclude the origin. Then $\vec{\nabla}^2 u_0 = 0$ in $\Omega$. In general I have a Poisson equation for $u$, where the source term $f$ is a given field. So, I know that I need $u \to u_0 = \theta$ when $f \to 0$, but I do not know how to formally express the solution to Poisson's equation. Where and how is $u_0$ included in the Poisson equation?

Comment: I guess I just don't understand why you would recover that particular harmonic function $u_0$ when you send $f \to 0$. Why would you not just recover the zero function? What in your problem is forcing that function out?

Comment: Indeed, this is what I am confused by. Apparently sending $f \to 0$ results in a convolution of zero with $G$, which should presumably be zero. But I know that in the limit $f \to 0$ I in fact get $\nabla^2 u_0 = 0$ whose solution in $\Omega$ for me is $\theta = \arctan2(y,x)$. Is this limit in fact a boundary condition, modifying the general formal solution for $u$? If so, how can I write the general solution $u$ to the Poisson equation $\nabla^2 u = f$, where $u \to u_0 = \theta$ when $f \to 0$? Somehow $u_0$ should then appear in this (formal) solution $u$. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's telling you that you don't just have a convolution solution in your Poisson equation at all. But you haven't given any auxiliary conditions.

Comment: The limit $u \to u_0$ as $f \to 0$ should not rule out a solution of the form (1) in my question?

Comment: If you had a convolution solution and f went to zero "sufficiently nicely" then the limit would be just zero.